# ASP.NET Core CSS isolation is not working for img tag

Tags: css, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC website. Working on CSS isolation, I found CSS isolation is not working for `img` tags.

`_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <img  src="~/images/logo.png" />
    </a>
```

`_Layout.cshtml.css`:

```
.navbar-brand img 
{
    width:100px!important;
}
```

This code is not working and the image is not getting the new width.
is there any way to work with CSS isolation for image tags in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found answer to my Question.

```
.navbar-div ::deep img {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Scope Identifier will be issued only for HTML tags and the parent component's scope identifier is applied to the div element, so the browser knows to inherit styles from the parent component.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0